# Find serial number of child

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose that I've a given html code:

```
<ul class="fmenu123">
    <li>city</li>
    <li>service</li>
    <li>hour</li>
</ul>
```

There are in jquery function `children` and selector `nth-child`. But how could I find a serial number of "mouseovered" child of this `ul` element - ie number `n` such that nth child of `ul` is exactly this chosen element? Which is the simplest method in jquery to find this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index)

```
$(".fmenu123 li").on("mouseover", function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    console.log("hovered element: " + index);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFuCV/)

Answer (score 0):

Count `previousSibling`s with `nodeType` 1 (to count just element nodes: I assume you want to ignore text and comment nodes) until you hit null.

```
function getElementIndex(node) {
    var index = 0;
    while ( (node = node.previousSibling) ) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1) {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Example:

```
$('li').on('mouseover', function() {
    var index = getElementIndex(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function, like so:

```
$('li').on('mouseover', function() {
    var n = $(this).index() + 1; // :nth-child() is 1-indexed, .index() is 0-indexed
    // do some stuff with n
});
```